# Querying Wordpress users closest to ACF date field: meta fields need resave for users to appear?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm querying my Wordpress users against today's date in comparison to a ACF field (for context: date joined).

```
// Anniversary fetch
if (! function_exists('custom_job')) {
    function custom_job($limit = 1000, $show_all = false)
    {
        $query = array(
            'number' => $limit,
            'meta_key' => 'employee_order',
            'meta_query' => array(
                'key' => 'employee_order',
                'value' => date('nd'),
                'compare' => '>=',
                'type' => 'NUMERIC'
            ),
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
        );
        if ($show_all) {
            unset($query['meta_query']);
        }
        $users = get_users($query);

        if (count($users) < $limit && !$show_all) {
            $query['number'] = $limit - count($users); // search extra users until limit is full
            $query['meta_query']['value'] = date('nd', date('Y')); // from the beginning of year index
            $extra_users = get_users($query);

            // this can include duplicate users in some cases
            foreach ($extra_users as $user) {
                $users[] = $user;
            }
        }

        return $users;
    }
}
// employee lists ordering meta field for users on update
add_filter('update_user_metadata', 'custom_employee_order', 10, 5);
function custom_employee_order($null, $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value)
{
    if ('employee_since' == $meta_key) {
        update_user_meta($object_id, 'employee_order', date('nd', strtotime($meta_value)));
    }
    return null;
}
```

This seems to return users in correct order in comparison to today's date. Although:

**Issue: Oddly or for some reason it's only returning users that I resave under Wordpress. Is this normal? How could I bulk resave all users if this is really neccessary?**

Comment: Is this a new field you added that existing users don't have?

Comment: It's an existing field that all users have data in from before. If I resave an existing user it appears in the query. @Scuzzy

Comment: How exactly was that data saved the first time? That should be done using ACF's `update_field` function or something comparable; using just WP core functionality often doesn't seem to do the trick, ACF stores something extra.

Comment: `'value' => date('nd'),` - why `nD` as date format? `n` is month without leading zero, and `D` is a three-letter textual representation of the week day. That doesn't make much sense to use as a format in a comparison context to begin with.